# Lightest possible SSRS Integrated Mode machine

Tags: reporting-services

I am building a SharePoint 2010 farm. One machine is designated for SSRS and we will be running it in Integrated Mode.

Per this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283190.aspx this machine must have "an instance of a SharePoint product or technology."

What is the easiest way to meet this requirement?

EDIT: Looks like it's spelled out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905869.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say a standard SharePoint Foundation installation. One WFE, and your SQL server that'll be running SSRS.

Comment: You can't mix SharePoint foundation and Standard (I have two WFEs running standard) and a SQL cluster for everything other than SSRS.

Comment: You didn't say you had a Standard farm already ;)

Comment: But yes, I think (from memory) it's a service application that exposes on a WFE - that doc you added on your edit should set you straight.

Comment: You're right, I didn't say that, sorry. Thanks for your help.